# In Terminal, can I find out the current Finder folder?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

It is commonly asked how to get a Terminal prompt *from* a Finder window.  I am asking the opposite.

I would like a command-line way of determining the working directory of the "current" Finder window.

Comment: What do you mean by "current" Finder window when Terminal is the active app? By definition, no Finder window has focus then...

Comment: and more what if Finder has several windows open - what is the current window?

Comment: The actual opposite would probably be `open .` in Terminal...

Comment: Why don't you just drag the current folder displayed in the Finder window to the Terminal application window command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following command will return the path to the frontmost Finder window, if that's what you're looking for:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to get the POSIX path of (target of front window as alias)'
```

Note that this cannot return a POSIX path if the frontmost window has no POSIX path. So if the frontmost Finder window has an ongoing/finished search, is a smart folder or other magical location (like your Mac under devices, which lists all the mounted volumes and the network).

Search/Smart folder/No Finder window returns:

> execution error: Can’t make «class fvtg» of window 1 of application "Finder" into type alias. (-1700)

And trying to execute the command when viewing your Mac:

> execution error: No result was returned from some part of this expression. (-2763)

Comment: This is a good answer. I use TotalFinder in "visor" mode (it retracts when you're not using it). If TotalFinder is retracted and I run that command, I always get the error message. If TotalFinder is pinned, I get the path as desired. Shame it doesn't work in pinned mode; oh well. **Use case**: I wanted to write a command-line tool to create a new file (text, word, excel, ...) in the "current" Finder window, by which I mean most-recently-focused. I've done it a different way using DTerm to open a mini-prompt _from_ the Finder window. Works well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A quick question from beginner, where did you find such OS-specific command. For example, a beginner may never hear such command `osascript`, so do you have a more systematic way to search what command you want other than randomly googling?

Comment: @Jason The osascript is indeed OS-specific – it tells the operating system to run an AppleScript (it's the command-line bridge between the GUI-based AppleScript and the Unix shell). MacOS X (well, now we're up to version 11) is the fusion of two longstanding operating systems: Unix and Mac OS, and this particular command links their two distinct scripting languages. So this particular command is deeply rooted in the dual citizenship of this OS.

Answer (score 4):

`pwd`: print name of current/working directory

`open .`: open current directory in finder

Comment: I'm not really sure, if this is the answer to your question. Also, what do you by getting a "Terminal prompt from a Finder window"?

Comment: I think you misread that one gentmatt. Edit: yup u realised.  I think he means things like 'prompt here' a service to open a terminal window from Finder where the path in Terminal is preset to the finder's path.  He's looking for the reverse function

Answer (score 4):

This guy has a great answer http://coderwall.com/p/vp9zlw

Define the two functions:

```
function ff { osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"'\
 -e "if (${1-1} <= (count Finder windows)) then"\
 -e "get POSIX path of (target of window ${1-1} as alias)"\
 -e 'else' -e 'get POSIX path of (desktop as alias)'\
 -e 'end if' -e 'end tell'; };\

function cdff { pushd "`ff $@`"; };
```

After that you can type `cdff` to cd into Finder directory.

Comment: Hi there, I've improved the formatting for you. Check out the live preview and the formatting guide when you write posts -- they're very useful. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using zsh with [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) the requested functionality is provided by the [osx-Plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Plugins). After activating the plugin in the configuration file (usually `~/.zshrc`) one can use 
`pfd` to geht the path to the current finder window and `cdf` to cd to it.

Answer (score 0):

`insertion location` is basically the target of Finder window 1 or desktop.

```
f() {
    cd "$(osascript -e 'tell app "Finder"
POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
end')"
}
```

There's a [bug on 10.7 and 10.8](http://www.openradar.me/9406282) where the target and insertion location properties refer to the second frontmost window after opening a new window.