# Copying the current directory's path to the clipboard

Tags: macos, finder

What's a quick way of copying the path to the directory that's currently open in Finder?

Copying that path is very easy in Linux and Windows file managers - you just need to copy it from the address bar. I don't see a corresponding option in Finder.

Comment: duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/37769/3117

Comment: @AdamEberbach I disagree, the question you linked is about starting a Terminal instance at the current Finder path, this is about simply getting the path

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by copying the path? Do you want it to the clipboard in expanded form `/Volumes/whatever/path/to/frontmost/window/view` or something else? Basically, what is the next step you are going to perform with the path once you have it?

Comment: @bmike: Yes, your example is correct. The next step could be anything that requires me to access that folder path again, either immediately or in the future. I may want to store that path in a document for future reference, or run some commands in the terminal that use that folder, etc. In Windows and Linux I often use it for navigating in a new file manager window by pasting the path, but I doubt that will work in OS X.

Comment: It says in the question "I would like a command-line way of determining the working directory of the "current" Finder window." - are you not asking to get the path of the current Finder window in terminal, Hippo?

Comment: @Adam: Not exactly. I'm looking for a quick method - similar to the ones I'm used to on Windows and Linux (i.e. either pressing a couple of keys or clicking and pressing a key or two).

Comment: Thanks for the great answers so far. I'll be trying out these in the coming days, and accept the one that works best for me, or the one that the community chooses. Keep your answers coming!

Comment: Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2731/12285

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder: Though that question is similar, there is a difference between getting the path for a file or folder in the Finder and getting the path for the active window, especially if something is already selected in that window.

Comment: What are you going to do with the path in the clipboard afterwards?

Comment: @patrix Is that really any of our business?

Comment: Depending on what he is trying to accomplish, there might be better solutions than Cut&Paste. E.g. if he needs the path in Terminal he can just drag and drop the file/folder into the Terminal window (without any Cut&Paste)

Comment: @BlankMan  Here is the answer to your second question http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40194/why-wont-the-finder-sort-when-clicking-on-the-column-headers-in-this-list-view

Comment: Could you flag the answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223155/5112 by @shahid610169 as the accepted answer ? TIA

Answer (score 87, accepted):

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Will copy the path for selected folder or file to the clipboard. Tried on El Capitan.

Comment: Thanks, this is the very exact answer I wanted to hear.

Comment: for me it's brining up "snippets" menu.. not sure if its some utility i added or part of os :(

Comment: Also working for me on macOS Montery

Comment: This does work and is the simplest solution of all the ones listed on this page.
But I found only if you press Command before Option. If you press Option first, it copies the entire folder! (macOS Ventura 13.1)

Being a reluctant Apple user (my employer only supports Macs, but I've always used Windows) I'm staggered at how complex some tasks are, such as this one.
Windows has the location bar (like a browser) and the location can be copied and pasted from there. It's clear where you are, and simple to 'jump' somewhere else. No 3rd party software required - as seems popular here!

Comment: For me, this is not working on macOS Ventura even pressing Command first.

Answer (score 39):

Next to the name of the folder in the Finder is an icon depicting that folder. This icon can be dragged to anywhere you need to accept a path - dragging to the Terminal or TextEdit in plain text mode will drop the path as text in the window or document. However, this does not work with all destinations - copying to a rich-text TextEdit document, for example, copies a link to the folder and not the path.

There are some [third-party apps](http://www.macworld.com/article/1057685/copyfilepath.html), some free, some paid, that add this functionality. You can also [create a service with Automator](http://rmp135.posterous.com/copy-finder-path-snow-leopard) ([or AppleScript](http://www.macworld.com/article/1133299/pathcopy.html)) to do it, but a simple and free method that I like, especially if you like to use the terminal anyway, is to invoke [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm) on the Finder window and run:

```
pwd | pbcopy
```

That will copy the current path to the Mac OS X clipboard.

Comment: Ooh - great use of DTerm. I never spent enough time to learn it's true power, but more people I know swear by it than at it.

Comment: @bmike Yeah, I don't use it much, but it was my first thought when I read this question (after discovering that Finder indeed does not have this functionality built-in by default). It has the advantage that DTerm is a general-purpose tool and not something that needs to be installed or set up for this specific purpose.

Comment: This is exactly what I use DTerm for most of the time!

Comment: Also good form to strip the presumptuous newline from pwd's stdout, with a `pwd | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`.

Comment: You can an alias to your shell initialisation file (e.g. `~/.zshrc`) so that `pwdc` will copy the current terminal directory to clipboard, like so: `alias pwdc='pwd | pbcopy'`

Answer (score 36):

You can use Automator to do this with a single keyboard shortcut that you can use from any app, and without installing 3rd party software.

This Automator Service will copy the path of the Finder's front window, rather than the path of a selected file or folder, so it won't affect what windows are open or what items are selected. The path that is copied is simply text, so it can be pasted anywhere that you can paste text.

1. Open Automator and create a new Service.
2. Change "Service receives selected" to `no input` (or "files or folders" to have it appear from a right click) and leave it set to `any application` (unless you only want it to work from a specific app, like the Finder).
3. Add a "Run AppleScript" action to the workflow.
4. Replace `(* Your script goes here *)` with:

   ```
   try
       tell application "Finder" to set the clipboard to POSIX path of (target of window 1 as alias)
   on error
       beep
   end try
   ```
5. Save the Automator Service with whatever name you'd like it to have in the Services menu.

This Automator Service will now be in your Services menu.

*Note:* This doesn't escape spaces, so if your path has spaces, you may need to quote it. For example, in Terminal, the path would need to be quoted, but in Finder's "Go to Folder" command, it would not. If you want it to copy as quoted, you can change `POSIX path` to `quoted form of POSIX path`.

[image: Copy Finder Window Path Service]

You can add a keyboard shortcut for the service by going to System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts, then click on "Services" in the left pane, then scroll down to the "General" section in the right pane until you find your service.

[image: Copy Finder Window Path Keyboard Shortcut]

Comment: Thanks, It is working for me, But one more thing I like to get that If I select some folder and get the "Copy Finder window path"  also giving current window path it not having what folder I selected. Can you help me how to get such a way, please? For example, I am in AA folder, AA contains BB folder. If I select BB folder and get the path it contains path till AA only not BB how to get path till BB.

Answer (score 32):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, then copy information under Where:

[image]

Comment: @daviesgeek thank you so much for inserting an image for me.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: @daviesgeek Just want to know, how can I do the command button like you edited in my answer?

Comment: You can use `<kbd>Command</kbd>`

Comment: This is broken in Yosemite

Comment: @ClintM Exactly, stupid Yosemite.

Comment: @ClintM You can still select and copy the text.  When you paste what you copied the arrows turn into slashes.

Comment: @brandaemon heh... then it's been "fixed"... it didn't work before

Answer (score 23):

If you need the path in Terminal/iTerm, you can just select the file/folder in Finder, copy it (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), switch to the Terminal and paste it (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

You can also drag and drop the file/folder to the Terminal/iTerm.

Comment: A useful answer to a newbie like me, instead of wasting a lot of time installing 'X' ware. Appreciated !

Comment: This answer is just simple and has no external install dependencies...

Answer (score 8):

If you use Alfred, you can select the items, press ⌥⌘\, and select Copy path to Clipboard.

You could also [assign a shortcut to a script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28272/3936) like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the clipboard to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
end
```

This would copy the paths of all selected items:

```
set l to {}
tell application "Finder" to repeat with f in (get selection)
    set end of l to POSIX path of (f as alias)
end repeat
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to (l as text)
```

There's [a bug on 10.7 and 10.8](http://www.openradar.me/9406282) where the selection, insertion location, and target properties refer to the second frontmost window after opening a new window. It affects both scripts and Alfred, but not Automator services. As a workaround, you could move focus to another application and back before getting the selection:

```
activate application "SystemUIServer"
activate application "Finder"
```

Comment: Good stuff; note that the bug also affects Alfred. If only _selected_ items are needed (2nd script), you can avoid the bug by modifying the script to operate on `input` and by assigning it to an Automator-based Service that receives `files or folders` in `Finder.app`. To work around the bug when obtaining Finder's insertion location (1st script), you can apply the following, uuugly, but effective hack (works on 10.8.2): hide Finder, then unhide it again after a short delay - this will cause Finder to report the correct selection/insertion location afterward; obvious downside: flashing.

Answer (score 8):

The MacYourself tip [Copy file or folder path to the clipboard in Mac OS X Lion](http://www.macyourself.com/2011/12/31/copy-file-or-folder-path-to-the-clipboard-in-mac-os-x-lion/) works for me on 10.7.4. Basically it leads you through the steps of creating an Automator service that can be used to copy the full path of files and folders from the Finder. You then use it by assigning a custom hotkey or use the right-click menu to copy the path to the clipboard when a file or folder is selected.

[image]

If it helps, you can also type the following command into the Terminal to get the Finder to display the full path to the current folder in its titlebar:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool YES
```

Use the following to turn it off again:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder _FXShowPosixPathInTitle -bool NO
```

Comment: Since you already have the AppleScript made (assuming that screen shot is yours), can you please upload it to a service like droplr.com and offer a direct download link please? It'll be more user friendly for the OP. Considering he's new to the Mac OS, i'm assuming he won't like fiddling around with applescripts/automator services

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX Seeing as the file lives in `~/Library/Services` I think describing a method to download the file then copy it here (as `~/Library` is hidden by default on Lion), then follow half the MacYourself instructions to add the shortcut would actually be more complicated. The instructions provided by MacYourself are pretty straightforward to follow.

Comment: works i guess. Lol for these types of questions, i'd usually use package maker to create an installer that takes care of everything as needed, but i'm on vacation =/

Comment: This appears to be a default on El Captain now

Answer (score 6):

Although this doesn't answer your question directly, I have a more efficient method of obtaining the file's path (presumably for it to be pasted into terminal or a text file, for example). Simply drag-and-dropping the file into a text field will automatically insert the file's path.

Answer (score 4):

Back a few years ago, I would always have the [pos utility written by Gary Kerbaugh](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/pos) to improve finder / terminal interaction.

- `cdf` would `cd` to the path of the frontmost Finder window
- `fdc` would open a Finder window at the current shell path
- `posd` would just dump the path

This coupled with `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` should fit the bill for getting arbitrary paths to text format and then into your clipboard.

I believe [homebrew has adopted part but not all of this package](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/pos.rb) so I'm not sure if you can find a workable version of all the above, but it was magic when I first started using it. Now I just use [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) to push files around without caring so much about recording a specific folder.

Comment: `posd | pbcopy` sounds like it would work. The rest seems nice to have (though won't `open .` work instead of `fdc`?)

Comment: It's unix - there should be n+1 other ways to accomplish most things even with n being sufficiently large. I like `open .` though - it's elegant.

Comment: unfortunately, `pos` is no longer in homebrew.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I know to get the path to a file or folder is to Get Info on the folder or file (select it, right-click and pick Get Info), and then in the middle "General" section, you can select and copy (command + C) the path.

[image: screenshot of file info with path]

As for your other question, clicking on column headers in list view in the Finder does allow you to sort ascending or descending.

I do not understand the last question you ask -- again, I'd say go to the file itself, right-click and do as I described above to get the path.

Comment: Broken in Yosemite.

Comment: doesn't exist on High Sierra

Comment: oh wait, it exists but without / but shown as arrow

Comment: but when you paste the result, the arrow pastes as a "/"

Answer (score 4):

Dunno why or what i do, but this exists on my PC (High Sierra 10.13.4)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, many things can be accomplished by dragging & dropping. Apple thinks you don't need to be able to access the file path conveniently because everything can be accomplished by drag & drop. I'm not completely of the same mind, but usually I can do what I want.

This is how common actions are performed on OS X where you would need a path in Windows or Linux.

- To just find out where you are in Finder, right-click (or <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-click) the folder name in the title area.
- In a file selection dialog, to navigate to an opened Finder location, drag the folder or any file from that folder onto the selection dialog. This will not move the file or folder like it does in Windows, but set the path of the File dialog instead. (You can also drag a the document proxy icon (from the title bar of most apps) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>-drag items out of the Dock to do this.)
- To get the path of a file in Terminal or another text-only Application, drag the file on the Terminal window.

What is not (easily) possible:

- Inserting the file path of a file that is supported differently in an Application. For example, dragging an image into TextEdit (in RichText mode) will insert the image itself instead of the file path.

Comment: Potential confusion: Although command-click is the correct action for what you're describing, the term 'right click' in OS X conventionally refers to 'control-click'.

Comment: @applehelpwriter It works with both Right-Click (which is [Ctrl]+Click) and [Cmd ⌘]+Click, so the sentence is absolutely correct, even though it was edited in by someone else

Comment: Agreed, but I didn't read it that way. The expression "right-click (or Command click)" doesn't parse as two different options, which should be 'do A or B'. Rather, it looks like one option which is given an alternative name in parentheses. That's why I prefaced my comment with 'potential confusion'.

Answer (score 1):

Since Yosemite now has Windows-like dropdowns in Info window and this is the top Google result, here's what I came up with:

1. Press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to bring up `Info` window, the `Comments` and `Preview` sections will be expanded by default
2. **Drag Preview's folder icon into Comment's textbox**
3. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the path to clipboard and undo the Comment change, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to close

Answer (score 1):

**As of macOS Catalina:**
Like @Kokizzu said, to get the "Copy  as Pathname", open your context menu (right-click or two-finger click). Once it is open, hold down the `alt/option` key to get that option to appear.

Answer (score 0):

To copy the active path in Finder, simply control-click the folder or file to bring up the contextual menu. Next, select `copy the_folder/file_you_want`. Following that, you can paste the path to a terminal window.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't copy the whole path (name only).

Comment: edited. Doesn't copy the whole path everywhere, but does to a terminal window. If that's what the OP was looking for, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a quick Automator Action.
The [Get first Finder Window Path](http://www.markosx.com/thecocoaquest/my_very_first_automator_action/?csspreview=true) action will to get the front most Finder windows Posix Path. 
It a beta, but is working ok. 10.8 only
It will return the Posix path of the front most open Finder window.

1, Open the zip and install it by double clicking on the action.

It will go into the Utilities Actions name 'Get first Finder Window Path'

2, drag it as normal to workflow area and add for example the 'Copy to Clipboard' action below it
[image]

The *Service selected* can be file or folder if you save it as a'Service' this will enable you to then also use the contextual menu when clicking on any file or folder. doing so will run the actions and only return the Same window result. Not the selected file or folder. Alternatively set it to 'none.

You can save it as a service or like me save it as an Application and then drag the app into the finder windows Toolbar.
Where you just have to click it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy Path Finder Button is by far the easiest method I've found to accomplish this. It's so simple – download it, put in your Apps folder, then drag to your finder's toolbar, done.

- [the download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/copypathfinderb/)
- [a writeup + short video](http://operating-systems.wonderhowto.com/how-to/copy-files-location-mac-os-x-with-free-utility-copy-path-finder-421994/)

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work with OS X 10.9. The application is reported as damaged when I attempt to run it.