# Can I copy from Finder the current Path?

Tags: finder, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying the current directory's path to the clipboard](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47216/copying-the-current-directorys-path-to-the-clipboard)

Is there a way to copy to clipboard the current directory I'm at? (I'm running ML).

EDIT: There is an option to simply drag the file/folder from Finder to the Terminal and it will automatically enter the path name.

Comment: Is this in order to open the path in terminal? I have a more elegant solution if that is the case

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX Yes, I would like to hear it then :)

Comment: Try `Go2Shell` to open the current Finder window in Terminal :)

Comment: Also check out [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm/).

Comment: @Caesium Awesome!

Comment: @jtbandes Awesome Sauce! I'm loving this!

Comment: @jtbandes is there a way to open current folder via DTerm when I'm in Finder? It would be better than Go2Shell because I'll keybaord shortcut

Comment: It automatically detects the current folder. You can just type a command and either press enter to run it, or command+enter to run it in Terminal. If you just press cmd+enter without typing a command it will open Terminal there.

Comment: @jtbandes Listen this is one COOL app! thanks you so much for letting me know this! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [DTerm](http://decimus.net/DTerm/), which gives you a hovering command prompt. It can automatically detect the current folder you're in (in Finder, or any document-based app). You can press <kbd>return</kbd> to run a command in the DTerm window, or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> to open a Terminal window.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a service to open a selected folder in terminal, which can be enabled from System preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services.[image]
It can either be assigned a keyboard shortcut, or be launched from the services menu:
[image]

Comment: That looks good however, after applying the change this option doesn't appear in Finder->Services->New Terminal At Folder

Comment: It opens the folder you have SELECTED. There are third party services people made with automator that open at the current location

Answer (score 0):

Copy the path of the folder shown on the title bar:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the clipboard to POSIX path of (insertion location as alias)
end tell
```

Copy the paths of selected items:

```
set l to {}
tell application "Finder" to repeat with f in (get selection)
    set end of l to POSIX path of (f as alias)
end repeat
set text item delimiters to linefeed
set the clipboard to (l as text)
```