# Copy directory from "Get Info" in Yosemite?

Tags: macos

I am a programmer who used to constantly copy directory of a file from its "Get Info" menu. Since Yosemite, the original pure path is replaced with a "user-friendly" kid-version directory, which cannot be copied. Like this.

[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47216/copying-the-current-directorys-path-to-the-clipboard](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47216/copying-the-current-directorys-path-to-the-clipboard)

Comment: He specifically saying that he used the first answer to that question until upgrading to Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6610989

One of the suggested answers - drag file into Terminal window or Safari address bar.